# Testing mouseover event in vue-test-utils

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am trying to make unit test for a @mouseover and @mouseleave event who's displaying a v-card-actions depending from the mouseover. I am using vue-test-utils in my vuejs2 webpack application. Here is what i found on the web : [vue-utlis mouse click exemple](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/guides/dom-events.html) . Thanks in advance to anyone who's helping

Here is my code actual html template code:

```
  <v-card class="menuCard pa-1 elevation-2 f-basis-0 my-2" 
@mouseover="isBlockAct = true" @mouseleave="isBlockAct = (!checked? 
false:true)">
 <v-checkbox v-model="checked" id="checkbox" class="diCheckbox ma-0" hide- 
details></v-checkbox>
  <v-card-actions class="myUpHere pa-0">
  <v-layout row :class="{'isAct': isBlockAct, 'isNotAct': !isBlockAct}">
 </v-card>
```

Here is what i tried in my spec.js code:

```
  describe("Over event", () => {
     it("shows the icons if the card is over or not", () => {
      const wrapper = mount(MenuRepasRecetteCard, {
        propsData: {}
      });
      wrapper.find(".menuCard").trigger("mouseover");
      expect(wrapper.find(".isAct").text()).contain("remove_red_eye");
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

u need to wait for the event to be processed by vue.

```
describe("Over event", (done) => {
    it("shows the icons if the card is over or not", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(MenuRepasRecetteCard, {
            propsData: {}
        });
        wrapper.find(".menuCard").trigger("mouseover");
        wrapper.vm.$nextTick( () => {
            expect(wrapper.find(".isAct").text()).contain("remove_red_eye");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Lars, really help to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

The `await` keyword can be used to wait for the trigger to complete:

```js
await wrapper.find(".menuCard").trigger("mouseover");
```

`async` would also need adding to the closure:

```js
it("shows the icons if the card is over or not", async () => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly I can't comment on Lars answer.
The docs say nextTick isn't needed.:

Vue Test Utils triggers event synchronously. Consequently, Vue.nextTick is not required.

-Source: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/dom-events.html#important

Comment: If clicking an element causes data() to change, then $nextTick() will be required if you are asserting that change within your test.